# Как вставить изображение иконки по центру ячейки в библиотеке phpexcel?

Tags: phpexcel, php, excel

Когда я выполняю такой код:

```
foreach ($statuses as $status) {
    $statusDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
    $statusDrawing->setName($status['id']);
    $statusDrawing->setDescription($status['description']);
    $statusDrawing->setPath(APP_PATH . 'modules/experiment/_img/status/' . $status['id'] . '.png');
    $statusDrawing->setWorksheet($firstWorksheet);
    $statusDrawing->setCoordinates('B' . $startRow);
    $statusDrawing->setOffsetX($offsetX);
    $offsetX += 15;
}
```

То картинка по мере увеличения строк уходит за пределы строк, к которой они были привязаны. По координатам  X все нормально.

Размер картинки `14x14px`. Размер строки примерно `10px`. Подгоном и уменьшением размера картинок проблема не решается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема актуальна не только для позиции Y, но и для позиции X. Толчком к решению стало правильное расположение по ординате X.

Итак, в код я не заглядывал, но полагаю что моя идея верна:
Библиотека использует размеры строки и ячейки по умолчанию. Для того, чтобы корректно указать позицию элемента, надо всем предшествующим ячейкам задать размеры, тогда позиция определяется корректно. В моем случае, мне необходимо было добавить следующий код:

```
//необходимая операция дл вычисления вертикального положения ячейки
$firstWorksheet->getRowDimension($startRow)->setRowHeight(12);
```

П.С.: Вот поэтому по оси X подсчиталось правильно, так как я для каждого столбца задвал размеры. 
Для тех, кто любит все оптимизировать, придется поднять картинки в максимально приближенную ячейку к левому верхнему углу, так как после картинок не стоит уже задавать размеры ячейкам так строго.

Буду считать свой ответ верным наличием более трех лайков.