# Помещение изображения в ячейку

Tags: php, phpexcel

Все картинки помещаемые на лист накладываются по верх ячеек и может плавать по всему листу, как вставить картинку именно в ячейку, фиксировано?
В самом Excel  картинка вставляется в ячейку только через VB. Но может это можно сделать как-то через PHPExcel.
Сейчас картинку вставляю так:

```
$sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(40);

$imagePath = dirname ( __FILE__ ) . '/excel.png';


if (file_exists($imagePath)) {
    $logo = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
    $logo->setPath($imagePath);
    $logo->setCoordinates("B2");                
    $logo->setOffsetX(0);
    $logo->setOffsetY(0);   
    $sheet->getRowDimension(2)->setRowHeight(190);
    $logo->setWorksheet($sheet);
}
```

Comment: На вот этот вопрос посмотрите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137298/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B5-phpexcel

Comment: Да это возможное решение. Но это решение, также помещает изображение по верх ячеек. А желательно помещать изображение в саму ячейку.